# keypress event doen't working properly in java script for me

Tags: javascript, html

here i am trying to check condition which is something like whenever user press key between (65 to 125 ASCII or key code)  then execute code else give error but it doesn't behave properly whenever i type key which has ASCII value  between 65 125 it will execute else statement

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>press key between 65 to 125 charcode</h>
<script>
window.addEventListener("keypress", checkKeyPressed, true);

function checkKeyPressed(e) {
  if(e.keyCode >=65 && e.keyCode <=125 ){
    document.write("got");

}
else{
  document.write("opps prees valid");
}

}

</script>
</body>
```

proper explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: This is an excellent candidate for debugging, you can either use breakpoints or add the keyword `debugger` to your code and then you can step through your code to find the exact issue.

Comment: thanks @wizebin but i already done with as you said but sill i didn't figure out whats a problem

Comment: In your snippet above, when I press character keys, such as `t`, I get alert "got", otherwise I get alert "please only text". Isn't that what you expect?

Comment: no i want when ever user press key between "a" to "}" as per ascii at a time always execute if statement

Comment: Can u give example for a key between 65 an 125 which doent work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers use `keyCode`, others use `which`. `keyCode` is standard JavaScript and of course not implemented in the same way by all browsers. So, do this:

```js
window.addEventListener("keypress", checkKeyPressed, true);

function checkKeyPressed(e) {
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;

  if ( key >=65 && key <=125 ){
    alert("got")
  } else {
    alert("please only text")
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Click here and press a key</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to verify that the user is only inputting alpha characters.

You can use something like this to verify what you want:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      function checkKeyPressed(event) {
        if (/[a-zA-Z]/.test(event.key)) {
          // The user entered an alpha character
        } else {
          alert('Please only enter text, You cannot enter ' + event.key);
        }
      }

      window.addEventListener("keypress", checkKeyPressed, true);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also change the regular expression in the if statement to allow additional types of input (for instance if you want to have numbers as well you could enter `/[a-zA-Z0-9/`)

I would like to suggest as well that you consider another method of restricting your user's input, people tend to dislike `alert`, perhaps instead you could instead listen for change events on an input and filter out unusable characters?

Comment: no alpha charterer with parenthesis

Comment: You could include parentheses in your regular expression like this `/[a-zA-Z\(\)]/`